# How to assign password to an oracle role in Oracle 11.2?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-administration

I have to create a rol with the only privilege of CREATE SESSION, i have already created but when i give the role to the user I can not connnect to de DB because the user lacks of CREATE SESSION privilege.

This is what I tried:[image: Steps for creating a connection role with password]

But at the end when I try to connect with the user alvaro_rol I recive this message: [image: ERROR] and it was supossed to connect to the DB because I create de role, I grant the CONNECT privilege to the role, i give the role to the user alvaro_rol and finaly I activate the role with the comand set role and I don know what to do next.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Give the user the `CREATE SESSION` privilege.

Comment: I want to give the CREATE SESSION privilege to the user only with the role with the password, is that possible?

Comment: @Alvaro - no, you need session to be able to connect, and can then do `set role your_role identified by role_password`. Requiring a password to get the session privilege doesn't really make sense - doesn't the account password already cover that really? A password-protected role can then give you additional privileges after you've connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to give the user the `session` privilege, either directly or through a non-password-protected role. [The security guide says](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e36292/authorization.htm#DBSEG99891) (emphasis added):

> You can protect a role authorized by the database by assigning the role a password. If a user is granted a role protected by a password, then you can enable or disable the role by supplying the proper password for the role in the SET ROLE statement. **You cannot authenticate a password-authenticated role on logon, even if you add it to the list of default roles. You must explicitly enable it with the SET ROLE statement using the required password.**

Since you can't supply the role password during login/connect, you will have to connect first - which requires the session privilege - and then use

```
set role rol_conexion identified by conexion;
```

Currently setting that role would be a bit pointless, but in reality you would have a role providing other privileges that need to sit behind the role authorisation - and not `create session`.

Comment: Ok, this solves all my doubts. Thank you so much!